# Need help to refresh a brush of a visual child object (a Border) within viewport2DVisual3D object class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, refresh

I am using the Planerator control which works great. The only problem is that the brush of the Border object I added inside it doesn't get changed. It rotates well, but the brush seems frozen. I tried many things, but no can do.

Control link: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WPF-MediaKit/blob/master/SampleApplication/Controls/Planerator.cs

I search a lot on many help sites, including stackoverflow. Here is what I tried without any success;

**Important: I am working from code behind, not XAML.It worked fine in XAML**

```
this.UpdateLayout();
this.InvalidateMeasure();
this.InvalidateVisual();
this.InvalidateArrange();

((UIElement)_originalChild).UpdateLayout();
var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(viewport2DVisual3D, 0);
((UIElement)child).UpdateLayout();
((UIElement)child).InvalidateMeasure();
((UIElement)child).InvalidateVisual();
((UIElement)child).InvalidateArrange();
```

From this code;

// Interactive frontside Visual3D

Viewport2DVisual3D frontModel = new Viewport2DVisual3D() { Geometry = simpleQuad, Visual = _logicalChild, Material = frontMaterial, Transform = xfGroup };

Now, after testing, I am suspecting that once the object is added inside Viewport2DVisual3D has a child, color & brushes don't get refreshed anymore, but it will until/before that point. See "Visual = _logicalChild" above.

I have no error message, it rotates well, but the brush and color of my border don't get updated if I change the color.

Here is my working markup;

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestPlaneratorInXAML"
        xmlns:Planerator="clr-namespace:Planerator;assembly=Planerator" x:Class="TestPlaneratorInXAML.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Planerator:Planerator x:Name="aPlaneratorControl" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" CornerRadius="5" Background="Black"/>
        </Planerator:Planerator>
        <Button x:Name="ChangeBackground" Content="Change background" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" PreviewMouseDown="ChangeBackground_PreviewMouseDown"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestPlaneratorInXAML
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ChangeBackground_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Border)aPlaneratorControl.Child).Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What "worked fine in XAML"? Please post your working markup.

Comment: Sure, here is the working markup.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to reproduce the problem from code behind, and everything seems find. At the moment, I don't know how to pinpoint my problem and reproduce it within a more simple environment. In order not to waste people time, I would like to put this request on pause until further investigation from my part.

Comment: I'm ashamed to say it, but the brush was frozen. I don't know why it was frozen or by what. I'm doing some research. I didn't frozen it explicitly in code.

Comment: I continued my root cause analysis, and it seems that the border gets rasterized inside the Planerator which cause de the border to be fixed. Still looking at the issue...

Comment: I mean to be locked instead of fixed...